# Enviar dados apenas para o sidebar.blade.php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-eloquent, laravel-5

Preciso montar um menu usando as categorias cadastradas. Como posso fazer isso sem usar uma `view`?

Tenho meu `layout.blade.php` com um `@include('sidebar')`
Minha consulta funciona na `view` `categorias.blade.php`, preciso apenas receber os dados da consulta no meu `sidebar.blade.php`

**CategoriaController:**

```
public function listar() {
    $categorias = Categoria::where('categoria_id', '0')->with('todasCategorias')->get();
    return view('categorias', compact('categorias'));
}
```

Fiz a consulta direto no `sidebar.blade.php`.
Funcionou, mas creio que essa não seja a maneira correta, alguém conhece outra forma?

```
$categorias = App\Categoria::where('categoria_id', '0')->with('todasCategorias')->get()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi usando o **Service Injection** do Laravel 5.1.

No meu `sidebar.blade.php` adicionei:

```
@inject('categorias', 'App\Categoria')

@foreach($categorias->listar() as $categoria)
    <li>{{ $categoria->nome }}</li>
@endforeach
```

**Documentação:** http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade#service-injection

Answer (score 1):

Veja o código abaixo.

Na linha do `return` use `with`, para dizer que você vai carregar a página **com** a lista de categorias. Você faz `withCategorias`. **Categorias** é o nome que você vai usar no `foreach` na **blade**. E a variável dentro é a variável que faz a consulta, `$categorias`.

```
public function listar() {
    $categorias = Categoria::where('categoria_id', '0')->get();
    return view('categorias')->withCategorias($categorias);
}
```

Depois na **blade** você faz:

```
@foreach($categorias as $item)
   $item->nome_do_campo
@endforeach
```

---

Pode usar a função `__construct()`

```
public function __construct(){
   $categorias = Categoria::where('categoria_id', '0')->get();
   view()->share('categorias', $categorias);
}
```

Depois aplica o mesmo conceito acima do `foreach` na `sidebar.blade.php`.

Comment: Diego, obrigado pela resposta. Acho que não fui muito claro. Na verdade esse sidebar.blade.php não está no categoria.blade.php. O sidebar estará em todas as páginas do site. Eu importo o sidebar no meu layout.blade.php

Comment: Sabe usar a função `__construct` ?

Comment: Sim, mas não funciona dessa forma. Lembrando que a `view` `categorias` não tem nada a ver com a `sidebar`. Na verdade onde tem `categorias` nem tem o `sidebar`.

Comment: O `sidebar` não vai em toda página ? É só colocar essa função `__construct()` no **controller** principal, que chama todas as suas páginas.